# Why do I receive unreadable data via serial Port on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, serial-port, decode, uart

I receive data with an Raspberry Pi3 from another device with an ATMEGA 8 Chip via serial port, what I receive should look like : `#00 341 341 332 13123 R-? ...`

But what I receive on my Raspberry is:

`b'\xff\xfa\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xfd\xff\xea~\xf8\xff\xfe\xfe\xff\xd5\xff\xfe\xfd\xff\xff\xfd\xff\xff\xff'`

My port config:

`port = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0", baudrate=115200, timeout=3.0)`

How do I decode this or do you have any other suggestions?

I already tried to encode to utf-8, ascii etc. 
I also tried codecs.
I just got errors or some more disturbing data. Nothin I can work with.

Comment: Reduce the baudrate by steps, looking at the data received at each speed. Usual speeds are 115200, 76800, 38400, 19200, 9600, 4800, 2400, 1200, ... The other thing to check is the interface - whether the line is RS232 (+/- 12V idles -12V), TTL (0-5V, idles 5V), or 0-3.3V idles 3.3V) - if it’s anything but 3.3V you need an appropriate interface chip between the wire and the Pi - dangerous (as it it might easily break your Pi’s serial input line) to apply anything outside 0-3.3V to the Pi.

Comment: If the ATMEGA sends regardless of the Pi end, might be simplest to find the baudrate using a serial terminal program on the Pi - there is a simple one built in to PySerial read the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Your baudrate is big, try it with a regular value like 9600, also verify you have the same baudrate on both side.

Comment: Thank you for your answer... I already tried some different rates, but 115200 is the only one i recieved something.

Comment: Also I don't know how to find out the Baudrate of the other device, because I don't have access to instructions. Or is there a way to measure it somehow?

Comment: You may can find it using an oscilloscope but you will not be able to find it with your RPI because serial doesn't include any negociation or syncronisation.

Answer (score 0):

check if the pi is throttling at high speeds the data is corrupted when the pi lowers the clock speed. The pi should be able to run at 115200 no problem.
I put my pi into power save mode and I have now no corruption at all.

echo powersave | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufr
eq/scaling_governor